# Swift frameworks fail to build when BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION is set to Yes

Tags: swift

This came up when trying to adjust our framework so it can be used make an XCFramework bundle.  All the frameworks build fine until you enable BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION (setting it to Yes in build settings).  When you do that compile errors like this come up @IBOutlet property cannot have non-'@objc' class.  All of this is being done in Xcode 11 beta 4 right now.

I've narrowed it down to UIKit subclasses in a lower framework being themselves subclassed in an upper framework.  That new subclass, when used, produces that error.  This subclass has to happen in another framework.

What I did was to extract out everything to the simplest form, so the classes (see the code) show show newly defined classes that have no content.  They compile and show the errors.  This let me eliminate anything that may have had to do with details of the actual classes.  It's the bare minimum to show what is happening.

I have not yet tried in an earlier Xcode yet, but I plan to just to get a baseline.

**My code**

This is a case of defining a class in one framework and subclassing it in another.  This example has 2 frameworks: "Framework 1" and "Framework 2".

First I define a subclass in Framework 1.

```
// Defined in Framework 1  
open class ImageSubclass: UIImageView {  
}
```

Then I successfully use it in Framework 1.

```
// Used in Framework 1.  This compiles.  
class MyViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: ImageSubclass!  
}
```

I switch to Framework 2 and use that class in an outlet.  This also works.

```
// Used in Framework 2.  This compiles  
class MyOtherViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: ImageSubclass!  
}
```

Still in Framework 2, I subclass what I defined in Framework 1.

```
// Subclass in Framework 2.  
open class BetterImageSubclass: ImageSubclass {  
}
```

Then I use that subclass in an outlet.  This gives me the error you can see on line 3's comment (in this snippet).

```
// Use new subclass in Framework 2.  
class MyBetterOtherViewController: UIViewController {  
    // Error: @IBOutlet property cannot have non-'@objc' class type 'BetterImageSubclass'  
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: BetterImageSubclass!  
}
```

**What I expect**

I expect the frameworks to build as they did before BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION was changed from No to Yes.  Instead I get a handful of compile-time errors all related to @IBOutlet and @IBAction in a higher framework.

i.e., @IBOutlet property cannot have non-'@objc' class type 'BetterImageSubclass'

Comment: I went to try this on Xcode 10.2.1, and apparently BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION is not even an option there.  So this is purely with Xcode 11.